# How do I sync two folders in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization

I have some files and folders on a USB drive connected to my iMac...I would like to sync them with a folder on my iMac...how do I do that?

Is there built-in functionality in Lion that allows me to do that, or do I have to use a 3rd party solution?

Comment: When you say "Sync", exactly what behavior do you want to see? How do you want discrepancies resolved?

Comment: I want to make sure both folders contain the same files (no duplicates). So if one folder has newer files and then it replaces the old ones in the other folder. Basically, they just transfer files that are newer - or the diffs of existing files.

Comment: And older files clobbered without prompting

Comment: Not necessarily, @Daniel.  Chronosync, for example, allows you to archive X versions of the older files for Y days.  Handy if you decide you want an older version back.

Comment: Use a launch deamon to automatically start rsync when your USB is connected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[arRsync](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/) is a free OS X GUI to the [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) command line utility. It will get you started on the path to rsync enlightenment. You can save common sync operations to recall them at a later time for easy rsync. And it supports the common rsync use case scenarios: push A to B but leave stuff that's in B but not A in place, push A to B and delete stuff that's in B but not in A, make A and B look the same (with a conflict report).

Comment: Some updates for Catalina or newer?

Comment: This is way too old, wont run on modern MacOS.

Comment: Meta discussion about whether to keep or delete this can be found [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/should-i-delete-an-accepted-answer-thats-now-very-out-of-date). It'll stay because the question specifically references Lion and the answer still applies if you're running Lion.

Comment: However, it’s a valid question whether there is a modern equivalent to this utility.

Comment: @Calion certainly, and an entirely new question should be posted to solicit those answers.

Answer (score 22):

If you are comfortable with the terminal, **rsync** is a great utility that will sync folders easily.  Take a look at a tutorial [here](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) (the tutorial is on an "Everything Linux" website, but the rsync utility comes with both Linux and Mac OS X).

### Example commands:

Copy/merge everything newer from **SOURCE** into **DEST**, do not delete anything:

```
rsync -va   /path/to/folder/SOURCE/  /path/to/folder/DEST/
```

Copy everything newer into **DEST**, and delete any items from **DEST** that don't exist in **SOURCE**:

```
rsync -va --delete   /path/to/folder/SOURCE/  /path/to/folder/DEST/
```

Be sure to include the trailing forward-slash `/` at the end of your folder paths.

A useful hint here is that you can *drag folders into the Terminal window* to have it insert the full path to that folder (or file), saving you lots of typing and typos.

Comment: Here's a nice hint on using Mac OS X's built-in *rsync* and *Automator* to make a GUI for this: http://www.bananica.com/Geek-Stuff/Synchronize-two-folders-on-a-Mac-with-Automator-and-Rsync/

Comment: If you're syncing in OSX, you probably want to add `--exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude 'Thumbs.db'` into your rsync command to avoid copying OSX metadata.

Answer (score 4):

Another donationware is [SyncTwoFolders](http://throb.pagesperso-orange.fr/site/index.html):

> This program synchronizes two folders. The oldest files will be replaced by the most recent, and in certain cases, some files will be removed.
>   Use the help tags to familiarize yourself with the options.
>   Be sure of what you are doing when you start a synchronization. If in doubt, do a Simulation. This will show you what will happen if you choose to synchronize, but no files will be replaced or removed.

Answer (score 3):

SyncTwoFolders is a free great app that's very useful and handy for Mac users. I use this to sync my GoogleDrive and Dropbox folders. [Here is the link to setup SyncTwoFolders](http://www.afrowhitey.com/articles/sync-two-folders-on-a-mac-with-aptly-named-app-synctwofolders.html).

Actually you can schedule a sync. You have to create as setting of your own for ex. "mysync' by clicking the '+' sign next to 'Last Settings' drop down and saving it. This 'mysync' will appear in your window to the right when you click the '*' button above the 'Synchronize' button.

At the bottom of that sliding schedule window you can set the time interval at which it can sync.

You need to keep the application running in the background for it do scheduled syncing.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good luck with Chronosync for synching folders/Macs.

Answer (score 2):

Install Xcode from the App Store and use File Merge.

Then you can open both directories, and compare individual differences and pick which one is "correct" (even down to lines of text within a file), merging the results to a new directory or over the top of one of the two you're comparing.

(it should be available in Spotlight after you've installed Xcode, if not open Xcode and from the Xcode Menu it's under "Other Developer Tool)

Comment: Useful utility!  Although a little bit cumbersome, nice that it shows all the changes before you merge.

Answer (score 0):

For a decent GUI based file synchronizer, check out File Synchronization (website found [here](http://nemesys.dyndns.org/FileSynchronization_EN.html))  It is a low cost ($15) utility that has nice control over the sync process.  GUI arrows give you a pretty good feel of what is going to happen, ensuring you use the tool properly and don't end up overwriting the wrong file.  Nice tool.

Answer (score -2):

I use Beyond Compare for Mac. I used it before on Windows and it is very good with maximum control.

http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php

Answer (score -3):

Free Dropbox account is great if you need to sync small amount of files with other devices too, but if you have many devices, you should either upgrade Dropbox or get Chronosync. I personally use both of these solutions, so all my Macs are basically in sync. :)

Answer (score -6):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) is the answer. Simple. Multi-platform. Free.

Give it a go!

Comment: Dropbox syncs between machines not a USN drive and a folder